# Password protected or private URL one-time viewable video access

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, one-time-password, vimeo-player, video-embedding

I have a requirement to upload over API a video and embed it to a WordPress page, which needs to be one-time viewable and then never accessible again. Also the video needs to have no buttons to stop/pause/rewind/rewatch; once you land on the page, it will start playing and you will not see the video ever again. The access can be granted either by URL sent by email or password protected.

Second option would be not embedded, can be viewable on some streaming or video providing service like youtube or vimeo or any other, just need the previously mentioned requirements regarding privacy (one-time viewable is most important).

Current solution is on wordpress web page which currently implements WordPress's **PPWP plugin**, to lock content per path with a password.

But this solution has a flaw.
Videos uploaded to let's say `www.wordpress-domain.com/video-storage/video1.mp4` need to be public to be embedded for instance to path: `www.wordpress-domain.com/page1/private-sub-page/`.
So if the user knows the video path (or paths) `/video-storage/video1.mp4` they can just paste the video urls and play all of the videos that should be "private".

So my question now is what would be the best solution to upload/share a video using API and make it one-time available as described in the requirements? Is there any tool/video hosting platform that enables this?

I have searched and looked up for instance Vimeo, but all vimeo offers is domain based links that are private, which is fine, but they don't offer one time views, which is a necessary requirement. And most of other video hosting apps offer the same functionalities as Vimeo does.